# Compare the contents of two objects

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a Typescript project where I want to compare two arrays that contain multiple equal character strings.

These are the objects that I want to compare:

```
let fff: object = [ 'CO_SER.csv', 'CO_INS.csv', 'CO_DAT.csv' ];
let sss: object = [ 'CO_SER.csv', 'CO_INS.csv', 'CO_DAT.csv' ];
```

When comparing them it shows me false:

```
console.log(fff == sss) ==> false
```

How can I compare the strings of both objects? Objects can be ordered differently. And if they are different, how can I get the strings that are not the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly a remark: I don't know why you're explicitly typing your arrays as `object`. If you remove this, TypeScript will correctly infer the type to be `string[]`.

### Don't use `===` to compare contents

Using `===` will compare non-primitive values, like an array in this case, by reference. So two different array instances, even with the same contents, will never be equal.

### Use `.every()` when the order is always the same

If the order in the arrays is always the same, you can use `.every` as follows:

```
fff.every((value, index) => sss[index] === value)
```

### Use `Set` when the order can vary

However, you mention that the order may differ. In that case, you want to use a `Set`. Sets can contain only one instance of a value, and can quickly tell you whether a given value is member of that set.

In theoretical terms, you are looking for the [*symmetric difference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of two sets. This is the set of values that are in either of the given sets, but not in both.

Here is a function that will convert the arrays to Sets, compute the symmetric difference, and return an array of values that are in one of the arrays, but not in both:

```
function symDifference(values1: string[], values2: string[]): string[] {
  const notTheSame = new Set<string>();

  const values1Set = new Set(values1);
  const values2Set = new Set(values2);

  for (const value1 of values1Set) {
    if (!values2Set.has(value1)) {
      notTheSame.add(value1);
    }
  }

  for (const value2 of values2Set) {
    if (!values1Set.has(value2)) {
      notTheSame.add(value2);
    }
  }

  return [...notTheSame];
}
```

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-microservice-7rzdp?file=/src/index.ts&previewwindow=console) where you can play with it.

#### Final note

You may be tempted to use Array's `.includes()` method instead of using Sets. However, for larger arrays, the complexity and thus performance will degrade exponentially because this loops over the array every time.

Answer (score 0):

When you're comparing them they result different because each array represent a different `reference` in memory.

If you need to check that the first array contains strings that are also present in the second array, you could do this:

```
fff.every(e => sss.includes(e))
```

The `every` method returns `true` if the function provided as first argument returns `true` for ALL the elements of the array itself.

If you need to extract the strings that are present in the first array but are not present in the second array, then you could do this:

```
fff.filter(e => !sss.includes(e))
```

If you need to extract the differences between the two array in general, then you could use a function like the following:

```
const diff = (a1, a2) => {
  const a = []
  const diff = []

  for (let i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
    a[a1[i]] = true
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
    if (a[a2[i]]) {
      delete a[a2[i]]
    } else {
      a[a2[i]] = true
    }
  }

  for (var k in a) {
    diff.push(k)
  }

  return diff
}
```